# detectron2 model evaluation error :Unsupported type found in checkpoint! epoch: <class 'int'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, object-detection, detectron

I was trying to evaluate detectron2 model separately using model.pth file in python using the below code:

```
import torch
import detectron2
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor
from detectron2.evaluation import COCOEvaluator, inference_on_dataset
from detectron2.data import build_detection_test_loader
from detectron2.data.datasets import register_coco_instances
from detectron2 import model_zoo
import os

# Step 1: Install required libraries if not already installed
# Step 1: Load test dataset
cfg = get_cfg()
# Set the device to CPU
cfg.MODEL.DEVICE = "cpu"
register_coco_instances("validation", {}, "test/output.json", "test")
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = os.path.join(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, "best_model.pth")
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.7   # set the testing threshold for this model
cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ("validation", )
predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)

evaluator = COCOEvaluator("validation", cfg, distributed=False, output_dir="./output")
val_loader = build_detection_test_loader(cfg, "validation")
print(inference_on_dataset(predictor.model, val_loader, evaluator))
```

But I was getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ajilson\Downloads\model_evaluation\model_evaluator.py", line 20, in <module>
    predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)
  File "C:\Users\ajilson\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\Sig-d\lib\site-packages\detectron2\engine\defaults.py", line 194, in __init__
    checkpointer.load(cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS)
  File "C:\Users\ajilson\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\Sig-d\lib\site-packages\fvcore\common\checkpoint.py", line 156, in load
    incompatible = self._load_model(checkpoint)
  File "C:\Users\ajilson\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\Sig-d\lib\site-packages\detectron2\checkpoint\detection_checkpoint.py", line 71, in _load_model
    incompatible = super()._load_model(checkpoint)
  File "C:\Users\ajilson\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\Sig-d\lib\site-packages\fvcore\common\checkpoint.py", line 273, in _load_model
    self._convert_ndarray_to_tensor(checkpoint_state_dict)
  File "C:\Users\ajilson\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\Sig-d\lib\site-packages\fvcore\common\checkpoint.py", line 369, in _convert_ndarray_to_tensor
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unsupported type found in checkpoint! epoch: <class 'int'>
```

When I tried to do the same in the notebook that I have trained the model, Its working. can anybody help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance